# Is this plywood board (in place of drywall) necessary due to drain pipe in shower wall?

Tags: plumbing, drywall, shower

Renovating a shower alcove. The drywall behind the fiberglass shower wall panels was cut out around the plywood you see in photo. When I replace the drywall with cement or greenboard, do I need to keep a plywood piece in that location? I assume it's there to protect cast iron drain and/or electrical box. There's a kitchen on the other side.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, but it looks like the plywood may have been screwed in place. If so, it was most likely intended to be an access panel. Now that it's a shower there instead of whatever _had_ been there, you don't want an access panel here as it will allow water into the wall.

Comment: @FreeMan - thanks. It is nailed on, and seems more like a protective barrier than access. I'm wondering if there's a code related reason for it.

Comment: If it was mean for protection, I think it would have to be steel.  Like what's used to protect wires and pipes that go through studs.

Comment: During demo found a note that it was "remodeled" in 1963. Unsure if they added that wood during the '63 remodel or if it was there before. Either way, sure seems like it's meant to protect the drain pipe. I think I'm going to eliminate it, and allow the green board to cover the entire wall, not notch around the wood.